# git checkout says files aren't committed, but they are?

Tags: git

```
(project_venv) jojo@jojo-System-Product-Name:~/project_fresh/examples/relational_preloadstack1/relational_stack1-layernormordertest-pkl$ git commit -m 'Huh'
On branch refactoringNormalizerIntoPreprocessingFnx
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   ../current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/preload_stack2_relational.py
        modified:   ../current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/resume_training_with_new_env.py
        modified:   ../current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/trace.html
        modified:   ../timing_test.py
        modified:   ../../../project/torch/core.py
        modified:   ../../../project/torch/sac/twin_sac.py
        modified:   ../../../scripts/convert_gpu_model_to_gpu.py
        modified:   ../../../scripts/download_s3.py
        modified:   ../../../scripts/inspect_hd5.ipynb
        modified:   ../../../scripts/sim_goal_conditioned_policy.py

no changes added to commit
(project_venv) jojo@jojo-System-Product-Name:~/project_fresh/examples/relational_preloadstack1/relational_stack1-layernormordertest-pkl$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        examples/relational_preloadstack1/current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/preload_stack2_relational.py
        examples/relational_preloadstack1/current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/resume_training_with_new_env.py
        examples/relational_preloadstack1/current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/trace.html
        examples/relational_preloadstack1/timing_test.py
        project/torch/core.py
        project/torch/sac/twin_sac.py
        scripts/convert_gpu_model_to_gpu.py
        scripts/download_s3.py
        scripts/inspect_hd5.ipynb
        scripts/sim_goal_conditioned_policy.py
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Why does trying to checkout the master branch give a "Please commit changes..." error here? You can see from the previous command that I already added and committed all changes to the 'refactoringNormalizerIntoPreprocessingFnx' branch

Comment: You haven't committed any changes yet, since you didn't add them to *stated changes*. You have to do `git add .` from the root folder of the repository or `git add ../../..` first, and then you can commit the changes. As you can read, git is telling you this: "Changes not staged for commit [...]" and "No changes added to commit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to commit changes without telling git *which* files to use for the commit.

Before you create your commit (with `git commit -m "Huh"`), you'll need to `git add` the relevant files that you want to be included.

For example, to add a **single file** to the changes, you can do:

```
git add ../current_preload_relationalstack1_to_relationalstackn/preload_stack2_relational.py
```

If you want to just **add all files** that have changed, you can do this (from the root folder of the project):

```
git add .
```

Note that this will also add "untracked" files to your commit - that means files that were not controlled by git in the past.

Once you've added your files, you can run `git status` again and you'll see a list of files that are "staged for commit". Once you have this you can add your commit:

```
git commit -m "Huh"
```

Now when you execute `git status` you should see a "nothing to commit" message.

Comment: I ran "git add ." but did not notice I was nested deep in a subdirectory. So the add didn't do anything!

Comment: You can do `git diff --cached` to see what changes are going to be committed, i.e. what exactly you have staged (added).

Comment: @user3180 - I've made a habit of running `git status` after almost any git command just to verify for myself that I'm in the state that I expect to be. :P